# Android: Display ImageView on the Activity after touching the Activity

Tags: android, android-imageview

Is it possible to display ImageView, on the Activity after I touch the Activity Screen.
I am able to get the x, y coordinate after I touch the screen. But unable to display the ImageView at the said location. Because there is no method to show the ImageView like we display the Popup Window using method, showAtLocation().

How it could be possible? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Did you try View.setTop() && View.setLeft() to place the image view at desired location?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the imageView margins to x,y from tap:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You can replace LinearLayout.LayoutParams with any MarginLayoutParams subclass

Comment: I tried, but imageview is not displayed. Please check the code below:

Comment: `int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();
LinearLayout parentLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLL);  
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelayout, parentLL);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
`

Comment: The imagelayout.xml is as follows:                       `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_notification_background" />
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

Set the margins of the ImageView to correspond to the x, y of the touch.